Allow tag-only edits when the post is mostly images/code
I'm editing tags on posts according to this post: What should we do with all of these symfony tags?.
Sometimes, when the posts are bad, I vote to close and/or downvote, but I still (sometimes) edit tags. But, for a few posts, such as this or this, I can't, because I get this error message:

Your post is mostly images. Add additional details to explain the problem and expected results.


Sometimes I just change the phrasing and it's fine. But, for the given posts, there isn't enough information to escape this.
So, even while editing tags only, it's asking me for this.
The problem is, I can't create information that I don't have, and I'll not remove the image (as it's the only information in the post...) or change the complete structure of the post.
Is it possible to allow tag-only edits on a post that are mostly code/images?

This post is bad, all that text should be text, not an image. The latter really isn't much better; it's falls into the "Help me" isn't a real question category. I'd VTC both of them.

@ThomA I know they are bad. But I will not re-write the full text from the image. I already voted to close both

Then what's the benefit on editing the tags? Would the questions be salvaged by the new tags? Better not to waste any more time in those posts.

@yivi whatever if they should be closed, they are wrongly tagged and will be on wrong tags. Also, it takes times to close, sometimes the vote expire and they are never closed, which means they will stay wrongly tagged

What's the point of tagging correctly a crappy question that would better be closed and deleted? What's the benefit?

This is a special case of "old questions that don't meet current filters don't get automatically dealt with, but resist small edits due to those filters". I especially run into issues trying to fix questions with terrible titles.

@Elikill58 spend your time fixing posts that are salvageable. If the post is in such a (bad) state that the system isn't even letting you change the tags then that's a sign that you probably should be VTCing and moving on. That'll push those questions into the review queue and will hopefully get closed.

@yivi Possibly, to draw attention to it from people in those tags who would more quickly notice that it should be closed and deleted.

I would agree, tags are not question content. They are meta data. But given recent experiments, it seems the company is already drawing their own plans when it comes to tags. I wouldn't get my hopes up of any kind of changes being applied even if this gets 400 upvotes.

Editing tags inline already let's you bypass most (all?) content quality filters.
This becomes available to you with the other moderator-tools at 10,000 reputation.

It is important to note that there are only 28094 users with that much rep, it would make sense to widen the pool of people that can do such edits Especially given that activity has dropped quite a bit on SO, so the number of active users (let alone those curating content) will be lower.

Ah so the tech already exists. Good, that should lower the threshold to make it more widely available.
